# TideSDK: Download mp3 files

Tags: desktop-application, tidesdk

I am trying to download an mp3 file from a server but the app crashes. The file gets created, gets some data in the file and then a crash. Here is what i am trying:

```
var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(directory.nativePath(), filename);
var httpClient = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();

httpClient.open('GET', URL);
httpClient.receive(function(data) {


    var fileStream = Ti.Filesystem.getFileStream(file);
    fileStream.open(Ti.Filesystem.MODE_WRITE, true);

    fileStream.write(data);
    fileStream.close();
});
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(directoryPath, filename);
var httpClient = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();    
httpClient.onload = function(e) {
        file.open(Ti.Filesystem.MODE_WRITE);
        file.write(this.responseData); // write to the file
    }
httpClient.open('GET', URL);
httpClient.send();
```